# Sub-Hypothesis Notation?

Tags: writing, writing-style

What is a standard way of notating sub-hypotheses? Should it be *H1, H1b, H1c?*

I’m revising a paper for a French author, and she’s written them with *bis* and *ter,* as in:

> **H1** (“cultural assimilation” hypothesis). Immigrants of Asian descent ... [then]
>
> **H1bis**. The aforementioned effect is stronger ... [then]
>
> **H1ter** ... .

I’ve never seen that before, but then again, there are a lot of things I haven’t seen.

Comment: *Bis*, *ter*, and so on sound like part of a Latinate number system. This might be favored by certain (Francophone) authors, but it is rare overall, as your unfamiliarity with it shows (it looks semitransparent to me because I had to study Latin way back in high school). I personally favor H1 for the main hypothesis and then H1a, H1b... for subhypotheses (and even H1ai, H1aii... for sub-subhypotheses, although whether you need to go that deep down is a different issue).

Comment: In my field (social sciences), H1a, H1b, H1c is standard. Some use H1.1, H1.2 and so on, which is also widely accepted.

Comment: Okay, so just to confirm: The main hypothesis is H1 and the first sub-hypothesis is H1a, followed by H1b, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's OK.

Comment: Okay, cool. I know that's exactly what Koldito said, but wanted a second opinion. ... I appreciate the help. It's not an easy thing to Google.

Comment: See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbe_multiplicatif for some information on your colleague's numbering.